# Effective way to get data that's needed on all pages

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using nodejs and express and I have a navigation menu that is built using data that is in mongodb currently I'm just making a call to the database to get a list of companies and passing that back inside each route. There doesn't seem to be a way to store this information in localstorage client side. So I"m wondering what is the most effective way to handle this situation. Sample of my code

```
admin.get('/', function(res, resp){
    mongodb.connect(url, function(err, db){  
        var collection = db.collection('companies')
        collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, companies){
            res.render('adminview', {companies:companies})//once the page is rendered I would like to save the company list to localstorage.
         })
    })
})  
admin.get('/:company', function(res, resp){
/* repeating code from above because I need this list */
     mongodb.connect(url, function(err, db){  
        var collection = db.collection('companies')
        collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, companies){
            /* more code to do stuff to render the company page */
            res.render('companyadminview', {companies:companies, company:company})
        }) })
```

I could be going about this the wrong way I'm new to web development this feels wrong to me but can't figure out a different way.

Comment: *"There doesn't seem to be a way to store this information in localstorage client side"* wut

Comment: @KevinB There's this thing called localStorage that can hold data on the client side you can read more about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: right. what makes you think you can't use it? some amount of caching here would be a good idea, either at the client level or the server level.

Comment: I'm using ejs on the front end there doesn't seem to be a way to get the data that is passed back i.e. <% localStorage.setItem('companies', companies) %> throws the error localStorage is not defined or something to that effect. Don't have the project running to give you the exact error.

Comment: uhm. ejs is serverside is it not? setting the localstorage server-side doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: Disclaimer: "I'm new to web development" Maybe i should add VERY new but thanks for letting me know now the error makes more sense.

Comment: @KevinB ok thanks, your input has been VERY helpful... I mean even the part where I said I could be going about this the wrong way. I mean you help answer every aspect of my question. cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first off you should be able to store it in localstorage or sessionstorage just fine, unless you're targeting browsers that don't support it.

That said, I think it's best *not* to, as the fact that you're storing it in the DB implies that it changes with enough frequency that you will get buggy clientside behavior if you cache it there for too long.

Instead, I'd just setup a middleware and attach it to the locals object on a per request basis, unless you want to do some kind of cache on the server:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  mongodb.connect(url, function(err, db){  
        if (err) return next(err);
        var collection = db.collection('companies')
        collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, companies){
            if (err) return next(err);
            res.locals.companies = companies;
            next();
         });
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah ok, I was reading about using next as well, that does seem like the way to go and good point about the data can be changed. I didn't factor that in.

Comment: @S.Will why didnt you give a point to this answer, or did you, and somebody else downvoted?  I was simply looking for the most appropriate initial way to load data for all routes, i.e. all pages, and indeed like you, for a navbar.  This topic is helpful, with the idea of cache to local storage (an example would be nice nere Paul, vs. a middleware call in the app.use statement.   Thanks for the tips.